# How to use condition WHERE json hierarchy column in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

I've created a small DW in Postgres that contains an XML column, JSON column and GEOmetry column , I want to use a clause group by in json column just.

let's focus on this table contains XML column, JSON column and GEOmetry column

[image]

I insert some line in the table.

here is the table view in postgres :

[image]

I want to display the lines with which the city is Tanger

note : I used the following query but it did not work :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on documentation the JSON operator are:

-The operator -> returns JSON object field by key.

-The operator ->> returns JSON object field by text.

Then You have a mistake with the operator, You must use ->  for addres key, for example like this example

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=67df669c90741366f89671ea9494b287
```

Answer (score 1):

```
columnName->>'field'
```

Accesses the field and returns the value as a string; whereas:

```
columnName->'field'
```

accesses the field and returns the values as JSONB, which allows you to continue traversing the object to lower levels.

So -> gives you JSONB ->> gives you strings